# Regex: How to optionally match something at beginning or end, but not both?

Tags: regex

I have situation where in the regular expression is something like this:
`^b?A+b?$`

So `b` *may* match at the start of the string 0 or 1 times, and `A` *must* match one or more times. Again `b` *may* match at the end of the string 0 or 1 times.

Now I want to modify this regular expression in such way that it may match `b` either at the start or at the end of the string, but not both.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Theres a nice "or" operator in regexps you can use.

```
^(b?A+|A+b?)$
```

Comment: +1, this works too, and you got it right on the first attempt. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^(bA+|A+b?)$
```

This allows a `b` at the start and then at least one `A`, or some `A`s at the start and optionally a `b` at the end. This covers all the possibilities and is slightly faster than the accepted answer in the case that it doesn't match as only one of the two options needs to be tested (assuming `A` cannot begin with `b`).

Just to be different from the other answers here, if the expression A is quite complex but b is simple, then you might want to do it using a negative lookahead to avoid repeating the entire expression for `A` in your regular expression:

```
^(b(?!.*b$))?A+b?$
```

The second might be more readable if your A is complex, but if performance is an issue I'd recommend the first method.

Comment: Now `^` applies only to first part of the `|` and `$` applies only to the second part.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(b+A+b?|b?A+b+)$
```

why doesn't that work?

Comment: I thinks he wants bbAAA _or_ AAAbb.

Comment: Actually b can repeat 0 or 1 times, and not more than 1 times

Comment: @Ngm: the word "repeat" is misleading; see how I edited your question for a better way to express your goal (I hope).  @Dan: in addition to the "0 or 1" issue, your regex matches 'b' at both the beginning and the end of the string, which the OP doesn't want.