# Regex with optional prefix OR Suffic

Tags: regex

I've used the | to successfully have optional terms in part of a string but now I need an optional string on either side of another e.g

```
(Near|In|Close to)(A|B|C|D|E)(Vicinity|Area)
```

where I will accept *either*:

- Near A
  or
- A Area

other then doing

```
((Near|In|Close to)(A|B|C|D|E))|((A|B|C|D|E)(Vicinity|Area))
```

I can't figure  out a way to use the optional flag to do something that looks more like

(Near|In|Close to)(A|B|C|D|E))(Vicinity|Area)

where it will accept either side

Comment: You can do: (Near|In|Close to)?(A|B|C|D|E)(Vicinity|Area) or also (Near|In|Close to){0,1}(A|B|C|D|E)(Vicinity|Area)

Comment: Do you also want it to accept if neither are applied? So that you only have "A" or "B"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex: How to optionally match something at beginning or end, but not both?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153266/regex-how-to-optionally-match-something-at-beginning-or-end-but-not-both)

Comment: What language are you writing this in? i.e. which regex engine?

Comment: @ClickRick I am using regex php

Comment: @LaughDonor It has to be either the prefix regix or the suffix regix it cannot be standlone.

Comment: @Fede I tried that but it seems to mean optional prefix. I need it to do either PrefixA or ASuffix.

Comment: BTW the suggested post does not work for me as my middle/core stings is long so it doesn't seem efficient to duplicate it in the back and then the front.

Comment: Can both prefix and suffix be applied? Just verifying the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You should use lazy, possessive quantifiers `?+` on your capture groups:

```
(Near |In |Close to )?+(A|B|C|D|E)( Vicinity| Area)?+
```

I also had to add spaces in your matches, since you have spaces in your data.

You can also write it like this:

```
(Near |In |Close to )?+([ABCDE])( Vicinity| Area)?+
```

---

Demo: <kbd>http://regex101.com/r/qY1pI4</kbd>

Demo with non-capture groups: <kbd>http://regex101.com/r/wV3fU1</kbd>

Comment: Hi thanks the problem with that is it matches: Near A, A Area, A.  It is required to either have the prefix or suffix string to be matched. So I'm trying to avoid ((Near|In))(A|B|C)|(A|B|C)(Vicinity|Area)). I was hoping there was some way to have the options that bracket the core term be either/or w/o repeating the core.